# QTimer thread affinity

Tags: qt

In the documentation it says:

> In multithreaded applications, you can use `QTimer` in any thread that
>   has an event loop. To start an event loop from a non-GUI thread, use
>   `QThread::exec()`. Qt uses the timer's thread affinity to determine
>   which thread will emit the `timeout()` signal. Because of this, you
>   must start and stop the timer in its thread; it is not possible to
>   start a timer from another thread.

So when I have a `QTimer` object, Qt uses the object's (or it's parent's) thread affinity to determine which thread will emit the `timeout()` signal.
But what happens when I use the static member function `singleShot(..)` which does not need a `QTimer` instance, which thread will emit the timeout signal then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt is open source so best approach is to check [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1%3asrc/corelib/kernel/qtimer.cpp#L340-356).
So object of [internal class QSingleShotTimer](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1%3asrc/corelib/kernel/qtimer.cpp#L275) is created (it is `QObject` but not `QTimer`).
The most important line that ansewers you question is [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1%3asrc/corelib/kernel/qtimer.cpp#L291):

```
  connect(this, SIGNAL(timeout()), receiver, member);
```

There is no `moveToThread` so it works like that:

1. temporary object is created for current thread
2. the signal is emitted from that thread
3. the slot is called immediately if destination object is assigned to same thread
4. otherwise the slot invocation is queued in event loop of thread to which target belongs to.

see documentation of [connect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect) and values of its [5-th parameter (type of connection)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Note that if `msec` value is zero then invocation of slot is queued in even loop of thread which receiver belongs to (no temporary object is created).

Comment: I've observed a `singleShot` timer never actually executing its callback; I haven't produced a minimal complete example (so it's not worth opening a new question), but I'm *guessing* it has something to do with thread affinity. So I'm wondering if, in my version of Qt (I think it's 5.6.2-1), `singleShot` timers started in the wrong thread can actually fail to trigger the callback.

Comment: I'm betting you are invoking `singleShot` from thread which doesn't return control to event loop. Event loop processing is needed so `QTimer` could work.

Answer (score 1):

The `QTimer::singleShot()` function creates a QTimer object and does all the setup for the signals and cleanup internally.

The thread affinity will be to whichever thread was running that executed that function.

Comment: you are wrong, see my answer. `QTimer` is not created, but some object of internal class `QSingleShotTimer`.