# How Qt implements event loop in linux

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm curious about how exactly Qt implements event loop and signal slot under Linux
Does it use thread signals or does it use dbus under the hood or something else?

Comment: You could always download the Qt source and have a look; short of that, this might be of interest:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42311174/131930

Comment: On Linux, it may use this: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html  (or some of the standard POSIX alternatives, `poll` or `select`, check sources to be sure).